# Android spinner click outside spinner immediately?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-widget, spinner

When i click and open the "Spinner dialog dropdown",
i want to **click and trigger another spinner dropdown immediately** in same layout.

Example:
1. "spinner1" and "spinner2" in same layout
2. When i click "spinner1" and open its dropdown,
3. then i want to click "spinner2" and open its dropdown immediately
4. with no wait for "spinner1" close its menu for click "spinner2"
5. (and also "spinner1" should close its menu)

when i click after any dropdown is open, anywhere in screen is blocked for close the opened dropdown, can't click any view until dropdown is close?
**Is it possible to click any other view when dropdown is open in Android?**

Comment: See my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
     Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_category);
        final Spinner sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_category2);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        sp1.setAdapter(adapter);


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.values, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter2);


        sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                sp2.performClick();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
   }
```

Comment: "  sp2.performClick(); " in OnItemSelected() will works for you.

Comment: it always run when sp1 clicked? i want only click to "spinner2" to open its dropdown

Comment: @MarsPeople As per my knowledge only this is way to do so in android.

Comment: i edited my question more clearly thank you for answer.